# React Hooks useState changing multiple elements state in one mouseOver function only want to change the moused over one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

I have the followig componenet on line 61-67 controls some state of a editIcon, it works but it changes the values of state for the span above in a column for all the items in the column, I want it to only changle the column item or rowItem it's on to change state, ie; hover over span element and a edit icon is shown, not shown in multiple other spans.

It has to do with the face the state is changing in two spots, but I don;t know how to isolate the component to be the one being hovered only and not the other ones generated. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks ahead of time

HEre is my code

```
import Link from "next/link";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { INPUT_VALUES } from "./formBuilder";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { RiEdit2Fill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Wrap = styled.div``;

const Grid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 225px));
  background: lightgrey;
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; */
`;

const RowItem = styled.p`
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: lightyellow;
  }
`;

const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

const HoverableRow = ({ rowEdit, d, i }) => {
  const [editState, setEditState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <RowItem
      onClick={() => rowEdit(d.ref["@ref"].id)}
      onMouseEnter={setEditState(true)}
      onMouseLeave={setEditState(false)}
      className="test"
    >
      <span>
        {Object.values(d.data)[i] ? Object.values(d.data)[i] : "null"}
      </span>
      <span>
        {editState ? (
          <a>
            <RiEdit2Fill />
          </a>
        ) : (
          <a></a>
        )}
      </span>
    </RowItem>
  );
};

const Value = ({ data, i }) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const rowEdit = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    router.push(`rowEdit/${id}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data ? (
        data.map((d) => (
          <div key={`${Object.values(d.data)[i]}-${i}`}>
            <HoverableRow {...{ rowEdit, d, i }} />
            {/* <p>{d.ref["@ref"].id}</p> */}
          </div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>loading</p>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR("/api/data", fetcher);

  const { loading, error: inputError, data: inputNames } = useQuery(
    INPUT_VALUES
  );

  const [inputDataState, setInputDataState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const inputData = inputNames?.allFormInputVals?.data;
    setInputDataState(inputData);
  }, [inputNames]);

  //console.log(inputDataState);
  //console.log(data);

  data?.map((d, i) => {
    console.log(d);
  });

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Welcome to your Catalog</h1>
      <Grid>
        {inputDataState?.map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <Wrap key={item._id}>
              <div>
                <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              </div>
              <form>
                <Value i={i} data={data} />
              </form>
            </Wrap>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each `RowItem` into a different component, so that each can have a separate `editState`:

```
const HoverableRow = ({ rowEdit, d, i }) => {
    const [editState, setEditState] = useState(false);
    return (
        <RowItem
            onClick={() => rowEdit(d.ref["@ref"].id)}
            onMouseEnter={() => setEditState(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setEditState(false)}
            className="test"
        >
            <span>
                {Object.values(d.data)[i] ? Object.values(d.data)[i] : "null"}
            </span>
            <span>
                {editState ? (
                    <a>
                        <RiEdit2Fill />
                    </a>
                ) : (
                        <a></a>
                    )}
            </span>
        </RowItem>
    );
};
```

and change

```
<div key={`${Object.values(d.data)[i]}-${i}`}>
    <RowItem
        ...
```

to

```
<div key={`${Object.values(d.data)[i]}-${i}`}>
  <HoverableRow {...{ rowEdit, d, i }} />
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my code to how I thought you meant, but it says Too many rerenders

Comment: It sounds like you're recursively invoking a state setter somewhere, but there aren't any obvious places to see where that might be happening in the code. Is the edit state changing the problem?

Comment: sorry I am not sure what you mean by changing the problem. The only thing I can think of is that the setEditState is happening in the HoverableRow componenet which is in a map function itself. hmm...

Comment: The fact that the component is being mapped shouldn't be an issue. If you remove the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` handlers, are there still too many re-renders? If so, that indicates the problem is outside of the `editState` state logic. Are there too many re-renders *on pageload*, or do you have to hover over a row to induce the error?

Comment: If I remove the Mouseeffects it works, and it has too many rerenders on pageLoad.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. No state setter functions are being invoked on render in the code in the answer. Are you sure you copied the props correctly? Eg you need `onMouseEnter={() => setEditState(true)}` and not `onMouseEnter={setEditState(true)}`

Comment: had to do this `   onMouseEnter={() => setEditState(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setEditState(false)}`

Comment: I messed up missed the annoymous function